# Dois-je utiliser le participe présent avec un pronom tonique?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, syntaxe, pronoms-personnels, participe-présent

Je veux dire: "Lorsque je suis tombé et dormi, le soleil illumine le jardin".

Est-ce que je dois dire: "Je tombant dormant, le soleil illumine le jardin", ou "moi tombant dormant, le soleil illumine le jardin"?

C'est à dire, je veux savoir si je dois utiliser le pronom tonique ou non avec le participe présent. Merci beaucoup.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas bien ce que tu veux dire par  *Tombé et domi* ou *tombant dormant* ni l'un ni l'autre ne peuvent se dire. Peux-tu expliquer autrement ?

Comment: Je me demande si on n'aurait pas ici un hispanisme (*estar* + gérondif) *estaba quedando dormido* → Je m'endormais, ce qui expliquerait la demande d'un participe présent. Auquel il faut expliquer dans la réponse qu'en français ça n'existe pas.... *esperar a ver*...

Comment: *je suis tombé et dormi* — possibly an attempt at a word for word translation of "I fell asleep", meaning *je me suis endormi*.

Answer (score 2):

*Je, agissant ici en tant que aCOSwt, suis en mesure de répondre que ceci n'est possible que moyennant quelques précautions* ;-)

Tu vois dans la phrase ci-dessus que, il est possible de faire un pronom tonique sujet d'un participe présent... MAIS ce sujet doit impérativement être le même que celui du verbe principal de la phrase. (ici, c'est *je* qui *suis en mesure*)

Ce qui n'est pas le cas dans l'exemple de ta question qui (en ignorant l'abus commis avec le participe passé de dormir, je crois que tu voulais dire plutôt *endormir*) suggère *Je* en tant que sujet du participe présent alors que le sujet du verbe principal (illuminer) est le soleil.

En se forçant un peu (car il n'est pas très naturel ici) à reprendre un participe présent pour ce que tu veux dire, on pourrait suggérer :

*- Tombant (endormi / de sommeil), je devinais le soleil illuminer le jardin.*

Voire, tant qu'à en être au participe présent, la solution de wazoox :

*Tombant endormi, je devinais le soleil illuminant le jardin*

Sachant qu'il semblerait quand même plus naturel de dire :

*Je tombais (endormi / de sommeil) lorsque le soleil illumina le jardin.*

---

<sup>NDaCOSwt : Considérer nécessairement le contre-exemple tel que cité par *Eau-qui-dort* dans sa réponse qui vient fort à propos nuancer ma proposition initiale trop catégorique. Mais je vois mal comment l'adapter à l'exemple origine de ta question</sup>

Comment: Je me demande s'il/elle ne veut pas dire *Je m’endormais alors que le soleil illuminait le jardin* ?

Comment: @Laure : Oui, c'est ce qu'il m'a semblé aussi. J'aurais aussi certainement préféré *alors* à *lorsque* mais... comme l'OP avait écrit *lorsque*... je l'ai repris.

Comment: Je crois que c'est un hispaniste... en tous les cas c'est bien d'essayer de rédiger la question en français, c'est un des cas où je pense que les PO doivent faire un effort pour améliorer leurs questions, on a tous à y gagner, questions plus claires, réponses plus précises...

Comment: "Tombant endormi, je devinais le soleil illuminant le jardin" me paraît plus correct. Puis on ajoute un participe présent :)

Comment: @wazoox : Oui! Pourquoi pas en effet! Suggestion ajoutée à la réponse. Merci.

Comment: Oui, je ne pense pas que ce soit vraiment possible de tourner la phrase-exemple de la question en utilisant un participe passé avec un sujet apparent, mais comme la question portait sur un sujet plus large que cette phrase, j'ai trouvé qu'elle méritait une réponse plus générale en plus de celle-ci

Answer (score 2):

Les pronoms sujets faibles ne sont utilisables qu'avec les formes verbales finies, c'est-à-dire qui s’accordent avec leur sujet. Donc on ne rencontrera jamais de pronom sujet directement attaché à un participe ni à un infinitif (présents ou passés), à part la formule figée "je soussigné(e)" qui reflète un état de la langue où les pronoms sujets du français fonctionnaient davantage comme ceux de l'espagnol et où le participe agit comme un adjectif qui qualifie le pronom.

C'est plutôt rare d'utiliser un pronom fort comme sujet d'un participe passé (puisque leur sujet est en général co-référents de celui d'un verbe fléchi comme indiqué dans la réponse d'@aCOSwt), mais ça n'en reste pas moins possible, surtout quand on établit un contraste entre deux sujets :

> Charline dormant déjà et **moi me douchant**, il n'y avait personne pour répondre à la porte hier soir.

Comment: +1 pour le contre-exemple de fin auquel je n'avais pas pensé. Merci!